# Nginx reverse proxy not working with Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I need some help setting up Nginx with Puma and Rails on Ubuntu server at Digital Ocean (already spend a lot time on this).

I have the follow settings:

#### /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (I remove some commented lines)

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

#### /etc/nginx/sites-available/test_server

```
upstream app {
    server unix:/home/deploy/www/test_server/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name testserver.com.br www.testserver.com.br; # fake url
        root /home/deploy/www/test_server/public;
        try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app; 

        location @app {
                proxy_pass http://app;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
                               
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

#### /var/log/nginx/access.log

I can see a lot of requests (from my local machine, from the server at D.O  and lot of others IP's that I don't recognize).

#### /var/log/nginx/error.log

When I try to access `www.testserver.com/index` from my local desk

```
2018/06/02 12:21:25 [error] 27541#27541: *6 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/index" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: localhost, request: "GET /index HTTP/1.1", host: "www.testserver.com.br"
```

#### Firewall

```
Firewall is open to Nginx HTTP/HTTP (v6)
```

#### Symbolic link in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test_server

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Jun  1 16:25 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test_server -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/test_server
```

#### What I have until now

- When I make a request to the site I got this message:

> "Welcome to nginx! If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working..."

- I know Puma is working fine because I can make requests direct to the socket and it returns the correct page (Rails starts in production environment ~ all working fine).

#### Last considerations from my attempts

I believe that Nginx is not able to connect properly with Puma and find the right files to serve. From the error.log I can see Nginx trying to access the folder */usr/share/nginx/html/* when it should try to connect to the socket, right? Maybe permission is the problem? (I saw a lot of posts on SO with permission problems).

I don't know what else I can try.

Any additional information just ask.
Thanks in advance!

### Solution

As I deleted the nginx.conf file (not on purpose) and copy from the git rep., the new file was missing the `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` and `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` lines. After adding these lines inside the section Http, Nginx started serving correct.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` to see the configuration that `nginx` is reading. But you do not appear to include the file `sites-enabled/test_server` into your `nginx.conf` file.

Comment: @RichardSmith I already try nginx -T. About sites-enabled,  I already created the symbolic link, I post it on my question.

Comment: You may have the symbolic link top there, but your nginx.conf doesn't include that file. For example in mine I have the followig within my http section:

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

Comment: Also your http section is httpt instead of http

Comment: @AdamBirds That is true! I deleted the original `nginx.conf` (unfortanely) and copy this one from the rep. Now that you said it, I remember from this `include`. Thanks for the catch guys! I will update my code and give a feedback here!

Comment: @RichardSmith, as you saw the problem first, I will accept as correct if you wanna post an answer.